# The condition in the while loop, is it possible to fulfill it?

Tags: java, arrays

The assignment is from the faculty collection. I'm still learning, and it's not clear to me why the `!r.hasElements` condition is used to solve the "dividing two polynomials" task, because as I understand the code, it will never be possible to fulfill that condition.

Can someone help me clarify what it is about?

```java
public class Polynomial {

  private int [] coefficients;

  private int power;

  public Polynomial(int a, int b) {

    coefficients = new int[b + 1];

    coefficients[b] = a; /* If it can be translated, the free member a is placed on the last index */

    power = Power();
  }

  public Polynomial(Polynomial p) {
    coefficients = new int[p.coefficients.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < p.coefficients.length; i++) {
      coefficients[i] = p.coefficients[i];

    }

    power = p.Power();
  }

  public int Power() {
    int d = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < this.coefficients.length; i++) {
      if (coefficients[i] != 0) {
        d = i;
      }
    }

    return d;
  }

  public Polynomial add(Polynomial b) {
    Polynomial a = this;

    Polynomial c = new Polynomial(0, Math.max(a.power, b.power));

    for (int i = 0; i <= a.power; i++) {
      c.coefficients[i] += a.coefficients[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= b.power; i++) {
      c.coefficients[i] += b.coefficients[i];
    }

    c.power = c.Power();

    return c;
  }

  public Polynomial subtract(Polynomial b) {
    Polynomial a = this;

    Polynomial c = new Polynomial(0, Math.max(a.power, b.power));

    for (int i = 0; i <= a.power; i++) {
      c.coefficients[i] += a.coefficients[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= b.power; i++) {
      c.coefficients[i] -= b.coefficients[i];
    }

    c.power = c.Power();

    return c;
  }

  public Polynomial multiple(Polynomial b) {
    Polynomial a = this;

    Polynomial c = new Polynomial(0, a.power + b.power);

    for (int i = 0; i <= a.power; i++) {

      for (int j = 0; j <= b.power; j++) {
        c.coefficients[i + j] += (a.coefficients[i] * b.coefficients[j]);
      }
    }

    c.power = c.Power();

    return c;
  }

  public int coefficient() {
    return coefficient(Power());
  }

  public int coefficient(int power) {
    if (power > this.Power()) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error in degree");
    }

    return coefficients[power];
  }

/* If someone understands why the professor overloaded the name of the method, I don't see the role*/

  public Polynomial[] divide(Polynomial b) {
    Polynomial q = new Polynomial(0, 0);

    Polynomial r = new Polynomial(this);

    while (!r.hasElements() && r.Power() >= b.Power()) { // my problem
      int coefficients = r.coefficient()  b.coefficient();

      int power = r.Power() - b.Power();

      Polynomial t = new Polynomial(coefficients, power);

      q = q.add(t);

      r = r.subtract(t.multiple(b));
    }

    System.out.printf("(%s) / (%s): %s, %s", this. b, q, r);

    return new Polynomial[] {q, r};
  }

  public boolean hasElements() {              // It is read, for all and in the sequence "coefficients"
    for (int i : coefficients) {
      if (i != 0) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  @Override

.............

}
```

Comment: Why do you think it should never be true?

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect. Please provide the actual code that you are testing with.

Comment: For example, `int coefficients = r.coefficient()  b.coefficient();` is invalid Java code.

Comment: because the HasElement() method will return true if it encountered at least one element that is not equal to 0. And if it is a polynomial r, which I created with the constructor, to which I pass a reference to the current attributes of the object, at the first interaction I must have at least one element , (I think I'm not wrong that ! is for negation, so if it is declared to have, negation is false, and then && (conjugation) is false ) @RealSkeptic

Comment: Should I accept that code as an abstraction, because it is more of a mathematical product than Java. I have already deducted 4 days.

Comment: @SergejLavBojanić2022, _"... I think I'm not wrong that ! is for negation, so if it is declared to have, negation is false, and then && (conjugation) is false ..."_, well the statement reads, if _r_ does not have elements, and _r_ Power is greater-than or equal-to _b_ Power.  The negation is for _r.hasElements_ only, and not the entire _while_ condition.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have not fully understood the polynomial division algorithm.

By checking the [wikipedia page for polynomial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) , the Pseudocode section lists the following:

```
function n / d is
    require d ≠ 0
    q ← 0
    r ← n             // At each step n = d × q + r

    while r ≠ 0 and degree(r) ≥ degree(d) do
        t ← lead(r) / lead(d)       // Divide the leading terms
        q ← q + t
        r ← r − t × d

    return (q, r)
```

Your code seems to follow closely this pseudocode.
Now, going to the condition

```
while r ≠ 0 and degree(r) ≥ degree(d) do
```

its best translation would be

```
while( r.hasElements() && r.Power() >= b.Power()){
```

So in my opinion, negating the statement `r.hasElements()` is a mistake, and the `!` is a typo.

Please do a search on google like "github polynomial division", and check various implementations.
For example, the following [Polynomial Calculator](https://github.com/TunsAdrian/Polynomial-Calculator/blob/master/Polynomial%20Calculator/src/model/Polynomial.java) provides a roughly similar implementation:

```
public Polynomial divide(Polynomial divisor) {
...
while (dividend.getDegree() >= divisor.getDegree()) {
       //equivalent of degree(r) ≥ degree(d)
            Monomial auxiliaryMonomial = dividend.getMonomials().get(0).divide(divisor.getMonomials().get(0));//equivalent of t ← lead(r) / lead(d)    
            PolynomialUtilities.introduceMonomial(quotient, auxiliaryMonomial);

            singleMonomialPolynomial.getMonomials().add(auxiliaryMonomial);
            auxiliaryPolynomial = singleMonomialPolynomial.multiply(divisor);
            singleMonomialPolynomial.getMonomials().remove(auxiliaryMonomial);

            dividend = dividend.subtract(auxiliaryPolynomial);//equivalent of r ← r − t × d
        }
```

The main lesson to take from this implementation, and others that I've seen, is that in the while loop, the code only compares the degrees of the dividend and the divisor. **Checking whether the dividend has only zero coefficients is redundant**. If that would be the case, its degree would be zero, which would make r.Power() strictly less than b.Power() .

Thus, I believe you could safely turn

```
while( r.hasElements() && r.Power() >= b.Power()){
```

into

```
while( r.Power() >= b.Power()){
```

Answer (score 1):

> *'... it's not clear to me why the !r.hasElements condition is used to solve the "dividing two polynomials" task, because if I understand the code, it won't be possible to fulfill that condition (never). ...'*

The code is as follows,

```java
while(!r.hasElements() && r.Power() >= b.Power()){      // my problem
```

The `!` unary operator will affect only the statement it's assigned to, in this case *r.hasElements*.
Any other statement would not be affected.

*[Assignment, Arithmetic, and Unary Operators (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)*.

Additionally, there is some error in the code you've added.

The *add* and *subtract* methods are incomplete.
They are both missing a closing `}` character, and a *return* value.

And, the inner *for-loop* declares a duplicate *i* variable, so it doesn't run.

```
java: variable i is already defined in method add(Polynomial)
```

Also, since the *return* statement is within the *for-loop*, it only loops once.

```java
public Polynomial add(Polynomial b){
    Polynomial a= this;
    Polynomial c = new Polynomial(0, Math.max(a.power, b.power));
    for(int i=0; i<=a.power; i++){
        c.coefficients[i] += a.coefficients[i];
        for(int i=0; i<=b.power; i++){
            c.coefficients[i] += b.coefficients[i];
        }
        c.power=c.Power();
        return c;
    }


public Polynomial subtract(Polynomial b){
    Polynomial a= this;
    Polynomial c = new Polynomial(0, Math.max(a.power, b.power));
    for(int i=0; i<=a.power; i++){
        c.coefficients[i] += a.coefficients[i];
        for(int i=0; i<=b.power; i++){
            c.coefficients[i] -= b.coefficients[i];
        }
        c.power=c.Power();
        return c;
    }
```

Finally, the *divide* method has a line with invalid syntax,

```java
int coefficients = r.coefficient()  b.coefficient();
```

And, a line with a missing valid *this* reference.

```java
System.out.printf("(%s) / (%s): %s, %s", this. b, q , r);
```

```java
/* If someone understands why the professor overloaded the name of the method, I don't see the role*/
public Polynomial[] divide( Polynomial b){
    Polynomial q = new Polynomial(0, 0 );
    Polynomial r = new Polynomial(this);
    while(!r.hasElements() && r.Power() >= b.Power()){      // my problem
        int coefficients = r.coefficient()  b.coefficient();
        int power = r.Power() - b.Power();
        Polynomial t = new Polynomial(coefficients, power);
        q=q.add(t);
        r=r.subtract(t.multiple(b));
    }
    System.out.printf("(%s) / (%s): %s, %s", this. b, q , r);
    return new Polynomial[] {q, r};}
```